# get_position() does strange things when using a colorbar

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a matrix of data in which the x and y axes are logarithmic. I'm trying to use `imshow` to display the matrix, but since I want log axes I'm setting the ticks in the `imshow` axes to `[]`, and then overlaying another set of axes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# the x,y max and min are the log values
array = np.zeros((2,2))
array[1,1] = -1
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.imshow(
    array, 
    extent = (0,1, 1, 0), 
    interpolation = 'nearest').get_axes()
ax.invert_yaxis()

# add a colorbar
# cb = plt.colorbar()      # <----- THIS CAUSES TROUBLE
# cb.set_label('zbar')

ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
position = ax.get_position()
aspect = ax.get_aspect()

# overlay another set of axes 
ax_log = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon = False)
ax_log.set_xscale('log')
ax_log.set_yscale('log')
ax_log.axis((10**0, 10**1, 10**0, 10**1)) # old min and max but exponentiated  
ax_log.set_position(position)
ax_log.set_aspect(aspect)

plt.savefig('test.png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.close()
```

without the colorbar this works fine:

[image: with no colorbar]

but when I uncomment the lines adding a colorbar, I get a weird shift:

[image: with colorbar]

It looks like the colorbar somehow shifts the image slightly to the left, but given that I'm calling `get_position()` after I create the colorbar this seems weird. Am I overlooking an easier way to make this plot? Is there some easy fix?

Answer (score 2):

Searching around a bit, I found a workaround, maybe there's a better one...

The issue seems to be that `plt.colorbar()` will 'steal' space from the plot it's drawn on. It's still a bit strange, because I'd still expect `get_position()` to return the proper coordinates. But as a workaround I used `GridSpec` and the raw `Colorbar` constructor.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.colorbar import Colorbar

# the x,y max and min are the log values
array = np.zeros((2,2))
array[1,1] = -1
fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(10,11)            # create a 10 x 11 grid
ax = plt.subplot(gs[:,0:-1])    # make subplot on 10 x 10 part 
im = plt.imshow(
    array, 
    extent = (0,1, 1, 0), 
    interpolation = 'nearest', 
    axes = ax)
ax.invert_yaxis()

# add a colorbar
cb_ax = plt.subplot(gs[:,-1])   # put the colorbar on the last column
cb = Colorbar(ax = cb_ax, mappable = im ) # use the raw colorbar constructor
cb.set_label('zbar')

ax.set_aspect(1)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks([])
ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
position = ax.get_position()
aspect = ax.get_aspect()

# overlay another set of axes 
ax_log = fig.add_subplot(111, frameon = False) # can't use gridspec?
ax_log.set_xscale('log')
ax_log.set_yscale('log')
ax_log.axis((10**0, 10**1, 10**0, 10**1)) # old min and max but exponentiated  
ax_log.set_position(position)
ax_log.set_aspect(aspect)

plt.savefig('test.pdf', bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.close()
```

It's also quite strange that I can't use the `GridSpec` object to initialize the second set of axes (doing so makes the image disappear).